# The first time when something happens in the future

Tags: grammar

**What should be used when I want to tell about my upcoming experience of something in the future? I have come up with a few options and I am not sure which sentences are correct.**

1 Tomorrow will be the first time I go to New York.

2 Tomorrow will be the first time I have gone to New York.

3 Tomorrow will be the first time I will have gone to New York.

4 Tomorrow will be the first time I will go to New York.

a bit different situation

5 Is it going to be your first time purchasing with us?

6 Is it going to be the first time for you to purchase with us?

7 Is it going to be the first time you have purchased with us?

Comment: Take out the "it" in 1 thru 4: _"Tomorrow will be the first time I go to New York"_.

Comment: For the first time ever, I'm going to NY tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I consider that you are going to New York and this is your first trip to the city. If I've taken it right, of all, I'd prefer this one -

> Tomorrow, I'm going to New York for the first time.

A bit different situation. I'd prefer this -

> Is it going to be your first purchase with us?

**JFYI:** What I practice is - speak it loud and listen to your own words. Apply some common sense and you'll identify which fits better!

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted; I read it twice, it seems like a good answer to me. The only change I'd suggest is change "it" to "this" in your second sentence: _Is **this** going to be your first purchase with us?_ Also, the _going to be_ could be removed (_Is this your first purchase with us?_), but it's not egregious to leave it in.